# Delete column data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my database, I have username,password,address,city...etc.
With this code it delete the whole row from database :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from customer_registration where username='"+ Session["username"] +"'",del);
```

My database with data : 
[Db](http://postimage.org/image/atblleck3/)

How to delete certain column data, or set it back to *NULL*?
[Db](http://postimage.org/image/xeucx6r6z/)

Comment: Do you have a numeric primary key column? Or is username your primary key field?

Comment: You should [read about **why** to always use parametrized queries](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml) instead of your current approach....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update your record like that

```sql
update your_table
set some_column = NULL
where id = 123
```